# Difference between Discrete Wavelet Transform and convolution

Tags: wavelet, discrete-wavelet-transform, pywavelets, fast-wavelet-transform

Sorry in advance if my question is too dumb.
I'm going through the book of Mallat, and from what I understand, the approximation/wavelet coefficients $a_j[n] = <f, \phi_{j,n}>$ and $d_j[n] = <f, \psi_{j,n}>$ can either be computed by convoluting the signal with the appropriate function, or in a discret setting using a cascade algorithm.

But when I compare the results using `pywt`, I get very different results, and I do not understand the values returned by the Discrete Wavelet Transform.

Could somebody help me with what I'm missing here ?
Thanks !

My code:

```
import pywt
import numpy as np



if __name__ == '__main__':

    def f(x):
        return 2 * x - 1

    # Signal
    x = np.arange(0, 1, 2**-8)
    y = f(x)
    
    # Using pywt
    coeffs = pywt.wavedec(y, 'haar')
    # print level 0
    a_p0, d_p0 = coeffs[0], coeffs[1]
    print("DWT:         ", a_p0, d_p0)


    # Hand-made convolution at level 0
    def phi(x):
        return 1 if 0 <= x and x < 1 else 0
    def psi(x):
        return 1 if 0 <= x and x < 0.5 else ( -1 if 0.5 <= x and x < 1 else 0 )

    a_c0, d_c0 = 0., 0.
    dx = 1.e-5
    x_c = np.arange(0, 1, dx)
    for i in range(x_c.size):
        xi = x_c[i]
        a_c0 += dx * f(xi) * phi(xi)
        d_c0 += dx * f(xi) * psi(xi)
    print("Convolution: ", a_c0, d_c0)
```

Output:

```
DWT:          -0.06249999999999911 -8.000000000000004
Convolution:  -1.0000000000026593e-05 -0.5000000000000003
```

Comment: If you refer to Wavelet Tour, then I think chapters 1-4 only describe the continuous wavelet transform (CWT), not DWT; they're related but also very different. Your convolution code also doesn't look like convolution. [This resource](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~unjung/mylec/WTpart4.html) might help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was referring to the chapter 7, the coefficients defined by the scalar product seem also to be computable using the cascade algorithm defined as the Fast Orthogonal Transform.

For the convolution, I just quickly implemented for $j=0$ and $n=0$ in $a_j[n] = \int f(t) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^j}} \phi(\frac{t - 2^j n}{2^j}) dt = f * \bar{\phi}_j(2^j n)$ with $\bar{\phi}_j(t) = \sqrt{2^{-j}} \phi(2^{-j} t)$

I will try to look in CWT as well

Comment: I see -- Yes, there are some important differences. Not an expert on DWT but AFAIK it's just cascades of convolutions and subsamplings that are concatenated in the end, so the output isn't just any one convolution. On CWT I do recommend that same source, parts 1-3, also demos and implementation [here](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy).